# how to add django base.html to angular js pages?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-login

So I have created a project which has its frontend in angularjs and backend in Django rest framework. now I have created a django login page which should authorize all other angular pages.
so how can we extend the base.html in angularjs pages with static files.

my tree structure is as follows:

```
  project
    |
    |
   application
   templates
   manage.py
   project
    |
     settings.py
     urls.py
  public
     |
     static
     html files
```

Hope to get answer to this.

thanks

Comment: it would be better to keep angularjs pages away from django templates. AngularJS itself provides everything from templating to partial views etc.
Perhaps partials is what you need here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following.
In you templates folder add a file base.html. In this file import all css and js files. The base.html will have the ng-app, ng-view (or whatever your are using). For example:

```
<html ng-app="raceApp">
.
.
<div>
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <section ng-view autoscroll="true">
  </section>
</div>
</html>
```

Then in the static files you could have a folder static/js will all the angular files. Inside this folder (js) you should follow a structure based on the way you are writing angular. For example i am using components (totally recommend) so each folder represents a different component.

> ```
> /static/js/user-login/
> /static/js/user-login/user-login.component.js
> /static/js/user-login/user-login.module.js
> /static/js/user-login/user-login.services.js
> /static/js/user-login/user-login.template.html
> ```